# Efficient method of finding single unsorted element in array

Tags: arrays, binary-search

Assume an array of length `n`, which is sorted. (values are arbitrary, can be negative, not only ints)

One element is out of place, for example

`-1, 2, 3.0, 4, 5, 10, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14`

`n` can be large.

Is there a way better than `o(n)` to find that element?